# Chrome App deleting file automatically to create space

Tags: html, google-chrome-app, chromium, chromebook

We are developing a Chrome App, and using unlimited storage in manifest file.
If at some stage storage space is not left on chromebook, and application  does more download/file writing then Chrome OS automatically deletes the earlier downloaded files in order to create space for new files coming in.

Do we have any configuration/permission so stop this auto deletion of files and rather show an error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "persistent" type of storage. In the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#table):

User experience at subsequent requests for increased storage

Persistent

> Chrome prompts the user again.

Unlimited

> Chrome does not prompt the user after installation, regardless of the requests for increased quota by the app or extension.

Hope this helps.